# Numpy - Declare a specific nx1 array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm using numpy in python , in order to create a `nx1` matrix . I want the **1st** element of the matrix to be `3` , the **2nd** `-1` , then the **n-1** element `-1` again and at the end the **n** element `3`. All the **in between** elements , i.e. from element **3** to element **n-2** should be `0`. I've made a drawing of the mentioned matrix , is like this :
[image]

I'm fairly new to python and using numpy but seems like a great tool for managing matrices. What I've tried so far is creating the `nx1` array (giving `n` some value) and initializing it to `0` .

```
import numpy as np

n = 100

I = np.arange(n)

matrix = np.row_stack(0*I)

print("\Matrix is \n",matrix)
```

Any clues to how i proceed? Or what routine to use ?

Comment: Have you done any research? You say you’re new to NumPy, so have you read the docs?

Comment: Unfortunately , I'm usually the guy that doesn't read the documentation.

Comment: Booo D: Good read the docs, no excuses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to just do the following:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
a = np.zeros(n)

a[0] = 3
a[1] = -1
a[len(a)-1] = 3
a[len(a)-2] = -1

>>print(a)
output: [ 3. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  -1. 3.]
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Your code generates (n,) and not (n,1). Speaking of linear algebra and matrix multiplications, there is huge difference between what you wrote and what actually works.
To demonstrate your answer is incorrect:
multiplying an (n,) array by any 1xl array will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [97]: n=10                                                                   
In [98]: arr = np.zeros(n,int)                                                  
In [99]: arr[[0,-1]]=3; arr[[1,-2]]=-1                                          
In [100]: arr                                                                   
Out[100]: array([ 3, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  3])
```

Easily changed to (n,1):

```
In [101]: arr[:,None]                                                           
Out[101]: 
array([[ 3],
       [-1],
       [ 0],
       [ 0],
       [ 0],
       [ 0],
       [ 0],
       [ 0],
       [-1],
       [ 3]])
```

Comment: seems okay , but I want it working for different values of n , I think yours applies only to n=100 ?

Comment: I demonstrated this with n=10.  You don't need to use [n-2]

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 100 # you can set to whatever number you want
a = np.zeros((N,1)) # you must specify the dimension as a tuple if you want exactly Nx1 array.
a[0]=3
a[1]=-1
a[-1]=3
a[-2]=-1
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess something that works is :

```
import numpy as np

n = 100

I = np.arange(n)

matrix = np.row_stack(0*I)
matrix[0]=3
matrix[1]=-1
matrix[n-2]=-1
matrix[n-1]=3

print("\Matrix is \n",matrix)
```

[image]

Comment: The best think I can say about it is that it works ;)

Comment: De rien!? Does that code actually produce the desired result? I haven’t run it myself yet.

Comment: Oui oui regardez la photo . (Rusty french :P )

Comment: T’inquiète. En effet, t’as raison.

Comment: I'm right to worry ? Or I am right(the  solution) ? Such a long time since french course in high school :-(

Comment: Don’t worry, I meant that you are indeed right about the code working!